# Possible to allow static ip for computer on any LAN?

Tags: networking, network-manager, lan, static-ip

Here is my issue. I have two computers running ubuntu 16.04 with a static ip profile for in NetworkManager, this profile works according to the subnet and dns of this particular LAN.

These two computers are able to communicate to each other knowing beforehand what each others static ip is on the LAN(via a DNS through /etc/host).

However, now I need to be able to freely distribute these two computers in different LAN environments with different ip addresses. The manual fix is to update  /etc/host and the NetworkManager Profile for both machines.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple answer is NO, there is no simple way to do this.  This is the downside of using static IP addresses when dealing with networks.  It is way to easy to have 2 or more hosts with the same IP address causing a IP conflict and taking out multiple systems at the same time.  Or not having the existing Subnet of the static IP matching the new network it is being plugged into causing the host to not see anything.

Using Dynamic, or DHCP, addressing will help solve this problem allowing any system to be plugged into a network with little to no configuration on the user's part.

One of my favorite tools to use when it comes to IP addressing on networks is http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, besides simple network configuration, one of the important need of the OP is that two computer can connect to each other easily.

If both computer or at lease on of them have public IP, a simple dynamic dns service could help.

If both computer are behind nat/firewall at different LAN, then the most common way is that you use a VPN to allow one computer to join the other LAN, so they could be effectively on the same net.  And you could assign static IPs in this case if you are the administrator.